# Remove an item from a comma-separated string

Tags: php, replace, csv

Let's say I have a string:

```
cat,mouse,dog,horse
```

Is there a regex or a function that will work as follows?

```
    1)"cat"       return string ->"mouse,dog,horse"
    2)"mouse"     return string ->"cat,dog,horse"
    3)"dog"       return string ->"cat,mouse,horse"
    4)"horse"     return string ->"cat,mouse,dog"
```

I need to eliminate the selected item from the string and return the remaining parts of the string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You mean a function that removes a certain element? Try this:

```
function removeFromString($str, $item) {
    $parts = explode(',', $str);

    while(($i = array_search($item, $parts)) !== false) {
        unset($parts[$i]);
    }

    return implode(',', $parts);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/6rT0pfno)

Answer (score 9):

It's as simple as exploding the string ([`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv)) and then removing the searched term. If you have an array, then [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) makes it very simple:

```
 return array_diff(str_getcsv($list), array($search));
```

Comment: This would be my preferred solution although note that str_getcsv is PHP5.3+ only. If the OP is using shared hosting, there are still many hosing companies that are still running PHP5.2.

Comment: @liquorvicar: That's only a small obstacle. I'm suffering from a 5.2 host myself, but [`PHP_Compat`](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/) and [`upgradephp`](http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/) pretty much solve the issue. Some of the userland emulations even outdo the native functions, so it's sometimes beneficial to run 5.3 functions on a 5.2 server ;)

Answer (score 7):

[**Working demo**](http://codepad.org/M8rBSyEJ).

This converts both string inputs to arrays, using `explode()` for the list. Then you just do `array_diff()` to output what's in the second array but not the first. Finally we `implode()` everything back into CSV format.

```
$input = 'cat';
$list = 'cat,mouse,dog,horse';

$array1 = Array($input);
$array2 = explode(',', $list);
$array3 = array_diff($array2, $array1);

$output = implode(',', $array3);
```